# Cannot reach web service - JQuery Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call a service from Javascript. 
When I call the API Url with the params and headers from Postman, everything works fine.

But when I try to call the same URL with the same params and headers in my code, it gives me an Unauthorized Error.

JQuery ajax code is:

```
var url = "https://website/getAll"
var headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Language': 'en',
    'apiKey': 'mykey',
    'identifierForVendor': 'myVendor'
};
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     data: { myData: 'myData'},
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "json",
     headers: headers,
     success : function(response) {
         alert('sss');
     }
 });
}
```

And the request is:
[image]

And the error:

> Failed to load "url...": Response to preflight request doesn't pass
>   access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1' is
>   therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

and in the response:

> no apiKey specified

Here is Postman Request:
[image]

anybody knows why? any suggestion? and why it is working correctly on Postman and not working on my code?

Thank you!

Comment: Try setting `Content-Type : application/json` in your headers. It doesn't seem to be doing it automatically.

Comment: It did not help, I guess the problem is that the code does not set any header correctly. I have changed the accept-language but it is still 'en' in the request. I don't know why

Comment: Yeah, that is odd. I can't help much anymore, best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in Server, the cors were preventing any outside request from accessing the APIs. It works by allowing them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are specifying your api information in the actual header of the request, when it should actually be specified in the data paramaters.

Try this instead:

```
var url = "https://website/getAll"
var headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Language': 'en'
};
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     data: { 
         myData: 'myData'
         apiKey: 'mykey',
         identifierForVendor: 'myVendor'
     },
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "json",
     headers: headers,
     success : function(response) {
         alert('sss');
     }
 });
}
```

I only suggest this because you 401 error's response is *no apiKey specified* which leads me to believe it is never being read. I'm not saying a method does not exist for specifying an apiKey as part of the request header, I've just never used `$.ajax()` in that manner before, I've only specified API credentials and such in the request parameters.

Comment: It did not work, unfortunately.  I updated my question with Postman data.